# VBA code to save data from sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a vba function in MS Excel to save data from one excel sheet to another, but it copies background formula instead of value.

```
Sub SaveData()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim erow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 7 To lastrow
        erow = Sheets("Sale_Register").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy Destination:=Sheet4.Cells(erow, 1)
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "Data Saved Successfully", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Alert"
End Sub
```

I want to copy displaying value instead of background formulas.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy (Append) Values of a Range to Another Worksheet

[image]

**A 'Quick' Fix**

```vb
Sub SaveData()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Worksheets
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Invoice")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sale_Register")
    
    ' Rows
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dRow As Long: dRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Additional Variables
    Dim srrg As Range, drrg As Range, sRow As Long
    
    ' Loop (slow).
    For sRow = 7 To slRow
        Set srrg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(sRow, "A"), sws.Cells(sRow, "C"))
        Set drrg = dws.Range(dws.Cells(dRow, "A"), dws.Cells(dRow, "C"))
        ' i.e.:
        'Set drrg = dws.Cells(dRow, "A").Resize(, srrg.Columns.Count)
        drrg.Value = srrg.Value
        dRow = dRow + 1
    Next sRow
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data Saved Successfully", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Alert"

End Sub
```

**An Improvement**

```vb
Sub CopyToSaleRegister()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Invoice")
    Dim rCount As Long:
    rCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 7 + 1
    If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = 3
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A7").Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sale_Register")
    ' or 'Set dws = Sheet4'
    Dim dfcell As Range:
    Set dfcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(rCount, cCount)
    ' i.e. 'Set drg = dfcell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)'
    
    ' Copy values (by assignment).
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "invoice copied.", vbInformation, "Copy to Sale Register"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case use PasteSpecial method

```
Sub SaveData()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim erow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 7 To lastrow
        erow = Sheets("Sale_Register").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy
        Sheet4.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "Data Saved Successfully", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Alert"
End Sub
```